# Alexa Skill is using previous invocation name even after rebulding

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I had to change my invocation name, because I got some issues when I submitted it for certification. I rebuilt my skill after changing the invocation name, but when I was testing it, the new invocation name was not working, and I realised that my skill was being launched with the old invocation name, instead of the new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebuilding is not the complete solution, if you contact Amazon support, they would tell that your skill is using the new invocation name, because it's right.
The hack for making changes to take effect is to **rebuild** your skill, **switch off** "Test is enabled for this skill" on test tab, and then **switch on** again.
After this, the skill will be using the new invocation name while testing it.

I friend of mine had the same issue, and this solved it.

Comment: Correct answer for current bug.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem. The new invocation name takes almost 30 minutes or so to change. The **Best Solution** is Change the invocation name before going to sleep, and when you wake up, the new invocation name will work like a charm.